# How can I get Mysql's DATE_FORMAT() to display hours over 24?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, time

I'm using `DATE_FORMAT(time, '%H:%i')` to get the time nicely formatted in `HH:MM` in a query, my problem however is that if the time goes over 24 hours it adds a day and the hour count will start again from zero, this way I can't display times like 40:00.

I have looked at the documentation here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format
But there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to display hours over 24, the only choices seem to be `00..23` and `01..12`, I'd be happy with something like `01..99` instead, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Last time I checked, there's only 24 hours in a day

Comment: I think you are attempting to use the wrong function here. Hours in the day will always be expressed from 01-12 or 00-23.

Comment: `time` in his case may actually be a delta time, describing the difference between two Date objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `TIME_FORMAT()` instead of `DATE_FORMAT()`. [`TIME_FORMAT()'s`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format) documentation says that

> If the time value contains an hour part that is greater than 23, the %H and %k hour format specifiers produce a value larger than the usual range of 0..23. The other hour format specifiers produce the hour value modulo 12